# Semicolon seperated value to other column in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

i have a table with a column have value seperated by semi colon.
the concern is value in the column are not fixed. it starts from 1 and end upto 80 semicolon sepaeration.
 i am trying to put each individual value to seperate column

**SQL SERVER 2008 code**

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE(
        Val VARCHAR(50)
)

INSERT INTO @Table (Val) SELECT '2Xcalcium; kidney' union all SELECT     '3XMagnessium; liver' union all SELECT '2-ECG;3XSODIUM;DIALYSIS'

SELECT  *,
        CAST(LEFT(Val,CHARINDEX(';',Val)-1) AS VARCHAR) FirstValue,
        CAST(RIGHT(Val,LEN(Val) - CHARINDEX(';',Val)) AS VARCHAR) SecondValue
FROM    @Table
```

I tried the above code but this is limited to 2 semicolon only. please share your expertise.

Comment: there are many such function around. here is one http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/   if you want the result in rows

Comment: here is another fnParseString() from http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=76033  ... this allows you extract the resulting element in column

Comment: And here is the article by Aaron Bertrand comparing different methods. sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE(
        Val VARCHAR(50)
)

INSERT INTO @Table (Val) SELECT '2Xcalcium; kidney' union all SELECT     '3XMagnessium; liver' union all SELECT '2-ECG;3XSODIUM;DIALYSIS';

;WITH Splitted AS
(
    SELECT *
          ,CAST('<x>' + REPLACE(Val,';','</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML)  ValuesAsXML
    FROM @Table
)
SELECT  *
       ,ValuesAsXML.value('x[1]','varchar(max)') AS FirstCol
       ,ValuesAsXML.value('x[2]','varchar(max)') AS SecondCol
       ,ValuesAsXML.value('x[3]','varchar(max)') AS ThirdCol
       ,ValuesAsXML.value('x[4]','varchar(max)') AS FourthCol
       ,ValuesAsXML.value('x[5]','varchar(max)') AS FifthCol
FROM    Splitted
```

The result

```
Val                     FirstCol     SecondCol  ThirdCol    FourthCol   FifthCol
2Xcalcium; kidney       2Xcalcium    kidney     NULL        NULL        NULL
3XMagnessium; liver     3XMagnessium liver      NULL        NULL        NULL
2-ECG;3XSODIUM;DIALYSIS 2-ECG        3XSODIUM   DIALYSIS    NULL        NULL
```

Comment: Thanks.. as usual you are the best.. :)

Comment: @akhrot Thx :-) There's one more thing to keep in mind: If your values contain forbidden characters (mostly `<`, `>`, or `&` you should replace them by `&lt;`,`&gt;` and `&amp;`

Answer (score 1):

Most of the link provided extract the element into rows.
If you prefer to use your existing logic and extract the individual element into separate column, you can use multiple cascaded CROSS APPLY.

```
SELECT  t.Val,
    v1.V as V1, 
    v2.V as V2,
    v3.V as V3
FROM    @Table t
    cross apply
    (
        select  V   = LEFT(t.Val, CHARINDEX(';', t.Val + ';') - 1),
            Val = STUFF(t.Val, 1, CHARINDEX(';', t.Val + ';'), '')

    ) v1
    cross apply
    (
        select  V   = LEFT(v1.Val, CHARINDEX(';', v1.Val + ';') - 1),
            Val = STUFF(v1.Val, 1, CHARINDEX(';', v1.Val + ';'), '')

    ) v2
    cross apply
    (
        select  V   = LEFT(v2.Val, CHARINDEX(';', v2.Val + ';') - 1),
            Val = STUFF(v2.Val, 1, CHARINDEX(';', v2.Val + ';'), '')

    ) v3
```

Answer (score 0):

From your question ,it seems that you have data in below format..This can be done easily with [numbers](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/62867/) table..

```
declare @string varchar(max)
set @string='s,t,a,c,k'



select substring(','+@string+',',n+1,charindex(',',','+@string+',',n+1)-n-1)
from 
numbers 
where n<=len(@string)
and substring(','+@string+',',n,1)=','
```

**Output:**

```
s
t
a
c
k
```

Few more Gems:
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/11506/why-are-numbers-tables-invaluable
http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings

Comment: i want to store in column and not in rows.